# listview show header without data source in react native?

Tags: react-native

when I click into some pages with data source from server.It do not have data show in cell but the data show in header.i debug my project found that it won't load header view without data source.what should I do can I load the header view?

Answer (score 0):

You should mount your header in your `render()` function independent of your `ListView`

If you intend on adding content to your `ListView` at a later time you could create an empty ListView.DataSource:

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2})
  }
}
```